# Integrating Twilio Video and Twilio Chat in one

Tags: android, twilio

I am trying to integrate `Twilio IP-Messaging` into an application that also uses `Twilio Conversations (Video)`. However, as per the change logs, IP Messaging SDK is using "`common-android v 0.3`" dependency, while,Conversations SDK using "`common-android v0.5`" dependency.

Because of this reason, i am not able to integrate both of them in one single application, either one of them suffers since both use different methods and also different versions of "`common-android`".

I have been referring to: [ip-demo-android](https://github.com/twilio/ip-demo-android) and they also use v0.8.1 of IP Messaging , which is the latest version.

I have also tried excluding the "common-android" dependency via gradle, but this unfortunately doesn't support the latest version of the conversations sdk.

```
compile ('com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.8.1+') {
    exclude group: 'com.twilio', module: 'common-android'
}

compile ('com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.twilio', module: 'common-android'
}
```

and added, common-android v0.3.1 jar explicitly in the libs folder.

I do not think there is any code required for this problem, but i am having issues in converting the following code snippet to use the latest common-android dependency

```
ipMessagingClient = TwilioIPMessagingSDK.createClient(
                            accessManager, props, BasicIPMessagingClient.this);
```

The `accessManager` that `createClient` takes as an argument is an instance of `TwilioAccessManager` while the new version of common-android, has a class `AccessManager` which is not compatible with `TwilioAccessManager`.

I would like to know if there is any other way by which i can create an ipMessagingClient of if there is a way to make both the modules work with different versions of `common-android` without causing multiple-dex errors.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked for, but I had a similar issue and want to share my approach. Twilios video feature is going to have a "data channel", which is "coming soon": https://www.twilio.com/video
Since I also struggeled with the IP messaging, I used PubNub instead (mainly because I used it in another part of my app). Again, I know that is not the answer you were looking for. But for now I would just use another service and wait for the "data channels" to deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution!

[Twilio: Android dependencies issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615118/twilio-android-dependencies-issue)

> Twilio Developer Evangelist here.
>
> We had a dependency conflict with com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.8.1, but have now fixed that and the fact that they use two different AccessManagers in 0.9.0. this should solve the problem you're encountering.