# Twilio: Android dependencies issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, twilio, twilio-api

I'm currently implementing two Twilio SDKs:

- Programmable Video
- IP Messaging Client

I'm realizing that one dependency affects the other, or at least so I believe, since I first implemented the `IP Messaging Client` and it worked flawlessly, and now that I've added the dependency for `Programmable Video`, when I try to run the project, it says it cannot find 3 of the used classes for `IP Messaging Client` in the package `com.twilio.common`, but those for `Programmable Video` are found. Here's part of the gradle (Module):

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
   compile 'com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.8.1'
   compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Also the classes that I have the conflict with of `IP Messaging Client` (they aren't in the package, the other clases are):

```
import com.twilio.common.TwilioAccessManager;
import com.twilio.common.TwilioAccessManagerFactory;
import com.twilio.common.TwilioAccessManagerListener;
```

And the classes of `Programmable Video` that I'm using:

```
import com.twilio.common.AccessManager;
import com.twilio.conversations.IncomingInvite;
import com.twilio.conversations.LogLevel;
import com.twilio.conversations.TwilioConversationsClient;
import com.twilio.conversations.TwilioConversationsException;
```

Note that class `AccessManager` from `Programmable Video` is the same and it's at the same level that class `TwilioAccessManager` used for `IP Messaging Client`, which in theory work equally. But the other classes can't be found.
I'm hoping anyone can help me! Regards!

Comment: What error do you get when syncing the gradle? if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

We had a dependency conflict with `com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.8.1`, but have now fixed that and the fact that they use two different AccessManagers in `0.9.0`. this should solve the problem you're encountering.

So please update your gradle file to be:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
   compile 'com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.9.0'
   compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

More information about this update can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/changelogs/android#ip-messaging-android-090-july-27-2016). Hope this helps you

Comment: thank you very much friend, this update came a day after asking the question xD